# How to Perform filtering and sorting or filtering different column in Flask_SQLACLHEMY

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a site where you can log in and then add your favorite animes and movies to your favorite list, for that I created a database and 3 tables `User`, `Anime` and `Movie`.

My database code:

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    anime = db.relationship('Anime')
    movie = db.relationship('Movie')


class Movie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(400), nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    ranking = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    review = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    movie_link = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class Anime(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    description = db.Column(db.String(400), nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    ranking = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    review = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    anime_link = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I want to first filter all the data with the current user id

```
(all_anime = Anime.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id.).all())
```

then sort them according to the ratings given by the user

```
(all_anime = Anime.query.order_by(Anime.rating).all())
```

```
all_anime = User.anime.query.order_by(Anime.rating).all()
all_anime = db.session.query(Anime).filter_by(id=current_user.id).all()
print(all_anime)

for i in range(len(all_anime)):
    all_anime[i].ranking = len(all_anime) - i

db.session.commit()
```

I know this snippet of code is wrong but I want to perform two different functions in two different columns how can I do it.

I also wanted to not accept the anime titles which are already present in the list of that user.

for that purpose, I have to filter the data with that user id

```
(anime_name = Anime.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).all())
```

and then filter the data with the anime title

```
(anime_name = Anime.query.filter_by(title=data['canonicalTitle']).first()))
```

```
@views.route("/anime/find")
def find_anime():
    anime_api_id = request.args.get("id")
    if anime_api_id:
        movie_api_url = f"https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime//{anime_api_id}"
        response = requests.get(movie_api_url)
        data = response.json()['data']['attributes']
        name = data["canonicalTitle"].replace(' ', '%20')
        description = data['description'].rsplit('.', 1)[0]

        # anime_name = User.anime.query.filter_by(title=data['canonicalTitle']).first()
        # if anime_name:
        #     flash("Anime Already exists In The List.", category="error")
        # else:
        new_anime = Anime(
            title=data['canonicalTitle'],
            year=data['startDate'].split("-")[0],
            img_url=data['posterImage']['medium'],
            description=description,
            anime_link=ANIME_SEARCH + name,
            user_id=current_user.id
        )
        db.session.add(new_anime)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Successfully Added.", category="success")
        return redirect(url_for("views.edit_anime", id=new_anime.id))
```

Comment: Have you tried a nested query? It could look something like this: `all_anime = Anime.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).filter_by(title=data['canonicalTitle']).order_by(Anime.rating).all()`. Basically, you can add as many queries as you like, and use them all at once.

Comment: @PatrickYoder thanks I will give it a try and then inform you about the result